# Split an array in freemarker template into multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, freemarker

I have an array, is it possible to split this array into sub arrays using freemarker.

Freemaker template how to split a existing array into sub array

```
<#assign monthsOfTheYear = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"] />
```

`"January", "February", "March", "April"  and   "October", "November", "December"`

`"January", "February", "March"` - should be in 1 array and .

`"October", "November", "December"` -- Should be 2nd array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes its possible to dynamically split the array into sub arrays one of the method is as follows.
- The following is an example of it

```
<#assign first = monthsOfTheYear[1..4] />
<#assign second = monthsOfTheYear[6..9] />
```

- If its a string you will have to probably convert into a number, assuming startdate and enddate are string with value say 02 and 04

```
<#assign sublistVar = monthsOfTheYear[(startdate?number-1)..(enddate?number-1)] />
```